# RegEx from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to validate a form in JavaScript, storing all the regular expressions in one object, but when I call any regex, it doesn't works

```
;(function() {

         var Rules = {
            "nick"     : '/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,20}$/'
          , "password" : '/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/'
          , "email"    : '/^[_a-z0-9.-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'
          , "name"     : '/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/'
          , "date"     : '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$/'
          , "country"  : '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/'
        };

        $('.validation-required').click(function(e){
          $(e.target).blur(function(){
            if( e.target.value( Rules [ e.target.name ] ) ) {
              console.log('true');
            }
            else {
              console.log('false');
            }
            $(e.target).unbind('blur');
          });
        });
      })();
```

So, always returns `"false"`; I tried something like this:

```
if( e.target.value( new RegExp ( Rules [ e.target.name ] ) ) ) ...
```

or

```
if( e.target.value( Rules [ e.target.name ].toString() ) ) ...
```

or

```
if ( Rules [ e.target.name ].test( e.target.value ) ) ...
```

in this case, the console throws an error:

```
(...) has no methd test
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entries you have in `Rules` are strings, not regex literals, because they're quoted.  Do this instead:

```
var Rules = {
    "nick": /^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,20}$/
    ...
```

Also, I'm not sure whether `if (e.target.value(Rules[e.target.name]))` is quite right... should it be something more like `if (Rules[e.target.name].test(e.target.value))`?

Comment: They should work with the `RegExp` constructor even if they are strings.

Comment: He is instantiating a RegExp object but isn't actually invoking the test method in his example.

Comment: @bažmegakapa They will give different results e.g.: `/[a-z]/.test("a") === true` and `new RegExp("/[a-z]/").test("a") === false`. The slashes are important!

Comment: @Sly_cardinal You are right, I did not take the slashes into account.

Answer (score 0):

Your final example reads `if (...).test`, which is a syntax error.